# Fixing News header Title/Images

Tags: css, html, content-management-system, fluid

I have tried so many different codes to really try snapping my news Title, date, Icon and background together. Right now if you go to http://crusadersscape.com/CSbeta/ you will see the little issue I am having in this (*Look closely at the news titled "CrusadersScape is getting a New Look!!"*), if you see that the News icon which is the CS image is not connected with the news background image.

With in my CMS I used the following code:

```
<div style="width:652px; margin-bottom:0px;">
<div id=news>{category-icon}{title}<em> <div style="float: right;">Posted on {date}</div></em></div>

<div style="text-align:justify; padding:0px; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; solid #D3D3D3;">{short-story}</div>

<div style="margin-top:0px;">by: {author-name}</div>

<div style="float: right;">[full-link]Read more[/full-link]</div>

</div>
```

Then in my CSS styling I use:

```
#news {
        left: 35%;
    height: 40px;
        width: 652px;
    padding-top:0px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
        background-image: url(/images/newsborder_header.png);
    background-position:inherit; 
        margin-left:0px;
        margin-right:0px;
        margin-bottom:0px;
        margin-top:0px;
}
#news_title {
        left: 35%;
    height: 40px;
        width: 652px;
    padding-top:0px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
        margin-left:0px;
        margin-right:0px;
        margin-bottom:0px;
        margin-top:0px;
```

What I am trying to do is have it all snap together with no issues and when ever there is a different category a different Icon will show. I am trying to get everything coded and looking right before I carry this out on to the main layout.

Answer (score 0):

add this in ur css file

```
#news img {
margin:0 !important;
}
```

or simply remove margin which is implementing inline on img tag

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because the image which contains the two "CS" letters got a `margin` with 2px.

Actually these 2px are added within the tag, If you opened the page source you will find this line for the image

```html
<img style="border: none; vertical-align: middle; margin: 2px;" alt="CrusadersScape icon" src="/images/CSnews_icon.png">
```

The fix for this is by removing the 2px, Which is the source of the problem

```css
#news img{
    margin: 0px!important;
}
```